# Check date and time with google calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to let the user chooses certain date and time and check the calendar if we have any events interfering with the user inputs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<base target="_top">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">

<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>From<input class="w3-input w3-border" type="datetime-local" id="from"></div>
<div>To<input class="w3-input w3-border" type="datetime-local" id="to"></div>
<button style="width:100%" class="w3-button w3-black w3-section" onclick="check()">check</button>
<div style="display:none" id="no">Not Available</div>
<div style="display:none" id="yes">Available</div>

<script>
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());// 2018-06-19T22:38:28+0000
</script>

<script>
function check() {
var startTime = document.getElementById("from").innerHTML;
var endTime = document.getElementById("to").innerHTML;
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("aqsv50qhum57qbh7a581cft1o0@group.calendar.google.com");
var allEvents = cal.getEvents(new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));
if (allEvents.length > 0) {
document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
}else {
document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried the above code but it returns nothing, thanks for helping

Comment: Where has this come from? `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());`? Java is a completely different language to JavaScript...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that was an old script I'm trying to adapt to my needs. I removed the section you highlighted but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is only for content WITHIN the brackets of the element.

For inputs you would need the value-property like this:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried .value but still the issue is the same. I do not know how to test the code through the website here if you can help